# Meteor iron-router IRLibLoader loading external JS files but none of the DOM elements inside template are loading

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using the meteor package IRLibLoader. It works great loading all of my external JS. I am able to call all of the JS functions from dev console to confirm that they are actually available. The problem... all of the DOM elements , for example div tags with id = foo.... I am unable to select any of them , they are all coming up undefined. The page is getting stuck to loading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up over complicating my issue.

The simple solution was for me to add the MyProject/public folder to my Meteor application.

For example:
MyProject/public/images/foo.jpg

I was then able to serve the content via the public folder and when any of my app needed access i would just put for example :